# 2 lines for the author block

Tags: titles, authorindex

I have a paper template that require that the authors should be written in the format:

```
XXX    YYY
Inst-111    Inst-222
Inst-333    Inst-444
email-1     e-mail-2
```

I have written it as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{coling2016}

\author{
  LastName1,\\ FirstName1\\
  \texttt{first1.last1@xxxxx.com}
  \\\And
  LastName2,\\ FirstName2\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
  \\\And
  LastName2,\\ FirstName2\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
  \\\And
  LastName2,\\ FirstName2\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
 \\\And
  LastName2,\\ FirstName2\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
 \\\And
  LastName2,\\ FirstName2\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
}
\title{Usage of the \texttt{\textbackslash author} command}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Coling template at: http://coling2016.anlp.jp/doc/coling2016.zip

However, because I have to add 5 authors I receive an overflow and it does not change line. I am not using the IEEEtrans template.

I would like to have 3 authors on the first row and 2 authors centered at the second row.

Comment: Please provide a small, functional LaTeX source code that shows the problem.

Comment: @gernot OK I have added a full example

Comment: Good. As you can see in the solution below, there was no chance to help based on the initial information alone.

Answer (score 12):

In `coling2016.sty`, there are three different and-commands: `\and` separates the name of authors with the same affiliation, `\And` separates authors with different affiliations on the same line, and `\AND` separates different lines of authors. See the comments at the beginning of `coling2016.sty` for more (?) information. Here is your example.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{coling2016}
\author{
  First Last 1\\
  Affiliation 1\\
  \texttt{first1.last1@xxxxx.com}
  \\\And
  First Last 2\\
  Affiliation 2\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
  \\\And
  First Last 3\\
  Affiliation 3\\
  \texttt{first3.last3@xxxxx.com}
  \\\AND
  First Last 4\\
  Affiliation 4\\
  \texttt{first4.last4@xxxxx.com}
  \\\And
  First Last 5\\
  Affiliation 5\\
  \texttt{first5.last5@xxxxx.com}
  \\\And
  First Last 6\\
  Affiliation 6\\
  \texttt{first6.last6@xxxxx.com}
}
\title{Usage of the \texttt{\textbackslash author} command}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using the HICCS-51 template \AND overlaps the text below. I can't find a solution yet.

Comment: Below `\usepackage{hicss51}`, add the line `\setlength\titlebox{6cm}` or whatever is necessary for the height of your author block.